# Dynamic Render Formula in XPages Menu

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xpages, lotus-domino

I created a computed Menu in XPages with rendered rules based on users roles.
The values of my menu are calculated from a view in a computed field.
This is my menu code:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul><li class='active has-sub'>
<a href='#'>Title1</a>
<ul>
<xp:text escape="true" disableTheme="true" contentType="html">
<xp:this.value>
<![CDATA[#{javascript:var arr= @DbColumn(@DbName(), "vwMenu", 4);
arr.join("");}]]>
</xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The value of an element from my array give for example this code :

```
<li class='has-sub'>
<a href=https://mylink.com>Link1</a>
<xp:panel>
<xp:this.rendered>
<![CDATA[${javascript:context.getUser().getRoles().contains('[USER1]')}]]>
</xp:this.rendered>
<ul>
  <li><a href=https://MyPage.com>Link2</a></li>
 </ul>
</xp:panel>
</li>
```

The menu appears fine so the html code is ok.But the xml part concerning the visibilty on link2 does not. link 2 is not visible, whatever the role of the connected user. I think it's a problem that happened where i use xml code into javascript code.
Maybe because The content type of my computed field is html and my code for rendering is in xml.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to enclose the `href` attributes with an apostrophe `'`:

```
  <li class='has-sub'>
            <a href='https://mylink.com'>Link1</a>
            <xp:panel>
                <xp:this.rendered>
    <![CDATA[${javascript:context.getUser().getRoles().contains('[USER1]')}]]>
                </xp:this.rendered>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href='https://MyPage.com'>Link2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </xp:panel>
        </li>
```

Comment: The menu works with or without apostrophe in the url. It doesn't work only when i put a rendering rule depending on a user role.

Answer (score 1):

Method `.contains()` is **case-sensitive**. Make sure the role set in ACL is exactly `[USER1]`. Your rendered code works fine for me.

You might add some prints to rendered code for test purposes:

```
        <xp:this.rendered>
            <![CDATA[${javascript:
                print(context.getUser());
                print(context.getUser().getRoles());
                context.getUser().getRoles().contains('[USER1]')}]]>
        </xp:this.rendered>
```

You can see at server console then what really happens in your code:

[image]

The `href` value has to be surrounded by quotation marks or single quotation marks. Otherwise you would get a syntax error and changes you did on XPage wouldn't take effect.

*Update*

As you mentioned in your comments, you put the HTML and included JavaScript code into a computed field. This doesn't work because the content is sent straight  to browser and this way included JavaScript code does not get executed on server.

Instead, use a **repeat control** to create the menu items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="https://mylink.com">Link1</a>
            <xp:panel>
                <xp:this.rendered>
                    <![CDATA[${javascript:
                        context.getUser().getRoles().contains('[USER1]')}]]>
                </xp:this.rendered>
                <ul>
                    <xp:repeat
                        var="link">
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                            ["https://MyPage.com", "https://www.google.com"]
                        }]]></xp:this.value>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#{link}">
                                <xp:text escape="true"
                                    value="#{javascript:'Link to ' + link}" />
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </xp:repeat>
                </ul>
            </xp:panel>
        </li>
    </ul>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.When i inspect my menu code into the browser, I see that the rendering part is commented . Normally the rendering rule  does not appear in the source code because it must be interpreted by the server.    

<xp:this.rendered>
<!--[CDATA[${javascript:context.getUser().getRoles().contains('[USER1]')}]]--></xp:this.rendered>

Comment: Even when i add the prints, they are commented when i inspect the source code. I have no prints on the console.

Comment: I updated my code with a working XPage. Go from there.

Comment: Thank you. When I inserts the source code directly in the menu XPage, rendering is done correctly. 
The problem is that I use a computed field to build my menu that recovers the values from a view. These values are the elements of my menu and are set by the user and calculated in a form (tags, rendering, title of the menu and the URL). when I recovers this computed code and insert it into my source code, it works well.
Except that my menu must be computed.
I think that the calculated field running the html part and not the javascript inside.